# CrafterCMS 3.0 Getting error while trying to preview changes by an author

Tags: content-management-system

I am getting the following error while trying to preview the changes made by an author.
This is what I have done

1. Logged in as a user with author role
2. Made a changed to a page
3. Requested to publish
4. Then logged in as admin user
5. There was one item added to the waiting for approval queue
6. Clicked on the name of the page to preview the changes. Got the following error

   ```
   [ERROR] 2017-05-11 15:23:52,374 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] [freemarker.runtime] | Error executing FreeMarker template
   FreeMarker template error:
   The following has evaluated to null or missing:
   ==> submitter.lastName  [in template "submitToApproval" at line 9, column 77]

   ----
   Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
   ----
   Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
   ----

   ----
   FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
       - Failed at: ${submitter.lastName}  [in template "submitToApproval" at line 9, column 75]
   ----

   Java stack trace (for programmers):
   ----
   freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
       at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)
       at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:355)
       at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
       at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
       at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
       at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
       at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
       at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
       at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v2.service.notification.NotificationServiceImpl.processMessage(NotificationServiceImpl.java:396)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v2.service.notification.NotificationServiceImpl.notify(NotificationServiceImpl.java:203)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v2.service.notification.NotificationServiceImpl.notify(NotificationServiceImpl.java:221)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v2.service.notification.NotificationServiceImpl.notifyApprovesContentSubmission(NotificationServiceImpl.java:178)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.service.workflow.WorkflowServiceImpl.submitToGoLive(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:225)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.service.workflow.WorkflowServiceImpl.submitForApproval(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:185)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.service.workflow.WorkflowServiceImpl.submitToGoLive(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:128)
       at org.craftercms.studio.api.v1.service.workflow.WorkflowService$submitToGoLive$1.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
       at scripts.api.impl.workflow.SpringWorkflowServices.submitToGoLive(SpringWorkflowServices.groovy:65)
       at scripts.api.impl.workflow.SpringWorkflowServices$submitToGoLive$1.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
       at scripts.api.WorkflowServices.submitToGoLive(WorkflowServices.groovy:113)
       at scripts.api.WorkflowServices$submitToGoLive$2.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
       at submit-to-go-live_post.run(submit-to-go-live.post.groovy:40)
       at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:605)
       at org.craftercms.engine.scripting.impl.GroovyScript.execute(GroovyScript.java:55)
       at org.craftercms.engine.controller.rest.RestScriptsController.executeScript(RestScriptsController.java:129)
       at org.craftercms.engine.controller.rest.RestScriptsController.handleRequestInternal(RestScriptsController.java:83)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.web.security.access.StudioAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.doFilter(StudioAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java:75)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.craftercms.engine.servlet.filter.SiteContextResolvingFilter.doFilter(SiteContextResolvingFilter.java:46)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.craftercms.engine.servlet.filter.ExceptionHandlingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionHandlingFilter.java:56)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.craftercms.commons.http.RequestContextBindingFilter.doFilter(RequestContextBindingFilter.java:79)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.web.filter.MultiReadHttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultiReadHttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:32)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   [ERROR] 2017-05-11 15:23:52,381 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] [notification.NotificationServiceImpl] | Unable to process notification message submitToApproval
   FreeMarker template error:
   ```